# Converting mov to mp4 with ffmpeg better quality

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mov

I want to convert mov videos to mp4. Currentoy I manage this with ffmpeg via bash with the following call:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -f mp4 -vcodec mpeg2video -acodec mp3 output.mp4
```

Yes that works, but the quality is abysmal. My 50Mb is shrunken to a handy 2.3 Mb file.
The I tried the variation where I just change the container:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -f mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 output.mp4
```

Yes that works, too, but the file is still huge since I don't compress the video. So my 50Mb stay 50Mb.

Is there a setting, where I can do a slight or gradual compression, without having a total lack of quality? an output file of maybe 10 - 20 Mb would be my target.

What I tried:

ffmpeg -i input.mov -f mp4 -vcodec -qscale:v 4  -acodec mp3 output.mp4

Gives me the error message:

WARNING: library configuration mismatch
   [...]
   Unknown encoder '-qscale:v'

Version used:
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: This is a broad question. What output formats do you require, or does it not matter? Why is it important to reduce the file size in this case? `WARNING: library configuration mismatch` generally indicates a broken `ffmpeg` build. If you mention your OS I can tell you how to get one that is not broken.

Comment: The desired output is obviously mp4. Why reduce the filesize? E.g. loading times via the internet. 

I use kubuntu 16.04 64 version and the ffmpeg, which comes with the distribution:
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: It isn't as obvious as it seems because MP4 is a container format that can accept several formats including MPEG-4 Part 2 video, H.264, and H.265/HEVC. You were attempting a variety of formats so I wanted to know which would suffice. Since it now appears you want to put it online it narrows it down to H.264 or H.265/HEVC.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Remux only

If your input video and audio are compatible with MP4 you can use [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy output.mp4
```

## Re-encode

If you need to encode to other formats compatible with MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -crf 23 -preset medium -movflags +faststart -c:a aac output.mp4
```

- Use the highest `-crf` value that provides an acceptable quality.
- Use the slowest `-preset` that you have patience for.
- If the input is AAC audio you can change `-c:a aac` to `-c:a copy`.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

Comment: This not working on web browsers. only play audio.

Comment: @MizanurRahmanKhan Need to see your command and the complete log to be able to help.